# Find Directory if Number of files is over X

Tags: shell-script, files, find

Am wondering if someone can advise on the best way to do this. 
In my Web Dir is around 100 folders; each folder is a clientID.

Within each ClientID folder is a Sub-Set of folders. 
In each subset of folders is a set of structured folders that are the same.

Example:

```
httpdocs/client1234/amazon/
httpdocs/client1234/ebay/
```

Within the Folder of Amazon and Ebay we have a directory structure like:

```
In/
Out/
Backup/
```

What I am trying to do is scan the whole Web dir and locate In folders that have more than 50 files in the IN directory.

**edited Included in the IN Directory. Only interested in File count on the IN dir.

Comment: The `In` folder has directories that should be counted too?

Comment: If one of the 3 answers solves your problem, don't forget to accept it with the green check-mark. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one-liner should work:

```
find httpdocs -mindepth 2 -name In | xargs ls -1 | awk '$0 ~ /httpdocs.*In/{name=$0; start=NR} (NR-start)==50{print name;}'
```

It will first find all `In` directories, then list all its files, and, finally, filter those with more than 50 files.

Adjust `-mindepth` according to your start folder.

Comment: `ls -1` will list the contents of directories if your `find` happens to discover one. Perhaps you want `ls -1d` or `find ... -type f`. But the whole thing will collapse if any of the filenames contains a space anyway.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'm waiting OP to answer my comment...

Comment: This is a perfect solution, Sorry for the slow reply
Filenames contain no spaces, This give me just what i was after. 
I was going to start filtering it down by file type, If you wanted to amend to include a filetype i.e. .xml Then that would be perfect. 

Its not required so if it cannot be done without re-writing then dont worry, But it would help when we have a server crash and am locatnig scripts that have not processed there IN Data.

Answer (score 2):

This will loop through the requested directories, counting the files (and subdirectories' files) to see if there are more than 50 files; if so, it echoes the matching directory/directories:

```
for dir in httpdocs/*/*/In
do
  count=$(find $dir | wc -l)
  if [ $count -gt 50 ]
  then
    echo $dir has more than 50 files
  fi
done
```

Note I used strictly "greater-than" 50 because `find`'s output includes that top-level "In" directory in its output to `wc -l`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
 for dir in `find ./httpdocs/*/*/ -name In -type d` ; do
  count=`find $dir -type f | wc -l`
  if [[ $count -gt 50 ]]
     echo $dir
  fi
done
```